# mongo $near returning double result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

When I run my Query on the table.loc it returns double result - really strange. There is only one instance of the result .

My Mongoose Sschema :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('debug', true);

var PositionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    code : String,
    loc : {type : [Number]/*long,lat*/, index : '2d'}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('position', PositionSchema);
```

query is :

```
db.positions.find({
 loc : {
  $near : [-6.3583374,53.3841475]    
 }    
}).limit(4)
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "there is only one instance of the result"? The $near operator returns the documents around the specified point from the nearest to the farthest. Furthermore you limit the query to 4 results. And it's 4 documents you get in the results.

Comment: from the PIC - in my DB collection there is only one code : L407 etc etc , code:value is unique. Yet the query still return double of them

Comment: Did you drop the duplicates when you created the index? db.collection.ensureIndex( { a: 1 }, { unique: true, dropDups: true } )

Comment: mongoose insure index with , index:'2d' . I haven't set unique in the schema , but there are deff no dups , from what I can see. Maybe I've picked you up wrong .

Comment: db.positions.ensureIndex( { code: 1 }, { unique: true, dropDups: true } ) , that done the trick - thanks. update schema now